# Из-за чего возникает такая ошибка?

Tags: linux, c

Из-за чего может возникать такая программная ошибка, как анализировать?

> unhandled page fault (11) at 0x60451d22, code 0x001

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> unhandled page fault

Это сообщение говорит о том, что при работе системного механизма управления страничной памятью произошла ошибка, но обработчика для этой ошибки не задано, поэтому программа аварийно завершается.

Около 90% ошибок такого рода возникает по двум причинам:

1. Индекс в массиве вышел за допустимый диапазон
2. В правой части выражения используется не инициализированный или ошибочный указатель на память.

Поймать, где произошла ошибка, проще всего следующим способом:

1. Компилируем программу с ключом *-g* (Включить отладочную инфорацию)
2. Запускаем программу под отладчиком *gdb*
3. После того, как программа упала, вводим комнаду *bt* - распечатать стек.

Там будет указана строка программы, в которой произошла ошибка.

Comment: что такое отладчик gdb

Comment: @Lofectr. https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/ https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger

Comment: Выполняем *man gdb*. Читаем: " gdb - The GNU Debugger. The purpose of a debugger such as GDB is to allow you to see what is going on "inside" another program while it  executes -- or what another program was doing at the moment it crashed." Это большая программа с широкими возможностями - пересказывать их все здесь нет смысла.